# All links broken, Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I am using Rails 4.

I want to force visitor to choose his country. There are only two options Latvia and Estonia.

In main layout I have like this:

```
 <li><%= link_to "Latvija", :country => :latvia %></li>

<li><%= link_to "Igaunija", :country => :estonia %></li>
```

In routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

 scope "(:country)", :locale => /latvia|estonia/ do  

  resources :reports
   devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
  ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
 #get "/accept" => 'home#accept_and_redirect'

   scope "(:locale)", :locale => /lv|ee|ru/ do  
     root 'home#index'

get 'advertisements/update_regions' => 'advertisements#update_regions', as: 'update_regions'

resources :reviews do
  member do
    put "like", to: "reviews#upvote"
    put "dislike", to: "reviews#downvote"
  end
end

    resources :advertisements do
         collection { post :search, to: 'advertisements#index' }
  member do
    put "like", to: "advertisements#upvote"
    put "dislike", to: "advertisements#downvote"
  end
end
   resources :services
    get "/help", to: "help#index"
  get "/rules", to: "rules#index"

 get "/blacklist", to: "blacklist#index"
  devise_for :users
    resources :users, only: [:show, :index] do
      member do
         put "like", to: "users#upvote"
         put "dislike", to: "users#downvote"

      end
    end
end
 end
end
```

What basically it does: It changes url to `http://localhost:3000/latvia/lv/users/sign_up` (works)
But when I go to `http://localhost:3000/latvia/lv/advertisements` it gives me error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"advertisements", :country=>#<Advertisement id: 82, name: "tij", region_id: 4, age: 19, height: 180, phone_number: "0202222", weight: 85,  email: "as@g.lv", description: "ahahi", created_at: "2014-11-28 14:39:12", updated_at: "2014-11-28 14:40:14", user_id: 14, country_id: 1, in_blacklist: false, admin_confirmed: false, vip: true, provaider: "few", your_ip: "wefwef">, :format=>nil, :id=>nil, :locale=>:lv} missing required keys: [:id]
```

So the links that is declared outside  `scope "(:country)", :locale => /latvia|estonia/ do   end`  works but those who inside don't.

What could cause this error ? Or it is other way to set country in link ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're just building the expected parameters wrong - or not passing everything that is needed. Take a look:

```
No route matches {
  :action=>"show", 
  :controller=>"advertisements", 
  :country=>#<Advertisement id: 82, 
    name: "tij", 
    region_id: 4, 
    age: 19, 
    height: 180, 
    phone_number: "0202222", 
    weight: 85,  
    email: "as@g.lv", 
    description: "ahahi", 
    created_at: "2014-11-28 14:39:12", 
    updated_at: "2014-11-28 14:40:14", 
    user_id: 14, 
    country_id: 1, 
    in_blacklist: false, 
    admin_confirmed: false, 
    vip: true, 
    provaider: "few", 
    your_ip: "wefwef">, 
  :format=>nil, 
  :id=>nil, 
  :locale=>:lv
} 

missing required keys: [:id]
```

It seems like `:country` is actually an instance of an `Advertisement` class - that doesn't really make sense to me, so that could be an error.  Probably your scope is messing with another parameter because they have the same name.

More importantly, since `:id` is nil, you need to pass an id to the `linked_to` call.  Like this:

```
link_to "Latvija", :country => :latvia, :id => <whatever you want this id to be>
```